# is there a shortcut/plugin to insert/list all object properties in vs like intellisense does for just one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Is there a way in visual studio to insert more than one (perhaps all) member/property from the intellisense of an object at a time? Or any plugins that will do this?

I am so tired of having to list them all out half-manually when building forms..

This would be a great shortcut if it exists..

Comment: I'm not quite following you...  Are you wanting a plugin where you could select all of the objects properties you wanted to reference?

Comment: Yes I'd like the intellisense list pretty much inserted into my code with the name of the object and scope resolution in place.  
o.prop1
o.prop2
etc

Answer (score 0):

There's [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [Code Rush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) which help with this type of thing.  They both have customizations so if it doesn't work how you want then you can add your own templates or add-in to make it do what you want.